# MQ Migrations vs New installation

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm in the process of migrating a MQ V7.5.0.3 to MQ V9.1.0.2.  According to literature, there is no direct path for this migration. I would need to migrate from V7.5 to V9.0 and then finally to V9.1

I would like to fast path this and go directly to V9.1 by:

1. dmpmqcfg V7.5 objects
2. delete qmgr the dmpmqcfg was issued
       against
3. uninstall V7.5
4. Install V9.1 and fixpacs
5. create new
       qmgr(same name as V7.5 instance) using the V7.5 dmpmqcfg output

Since this is a transitory migration to the latest level, it would seem that going through brief multiple Version installs just to do a MQ migration, is a lot more work than necessary.

My question is: If I bypass the multiple version migration process and perform the fastpath steps I mentioned above, will the end result be the same as if I did the multiple migrations?

Currently I have V7.5 and V9.1 installed side by side. Then I realized I would need to first go to V9.0, which I would like to avoid if possible. I could try the dmpmqcfg and create a new QMGR with it on V9.1, but I'm not sure that answers my question.

Comment: Are your queue managers part of a MQ Cluster?

Comment: No, the Queue manager is not cluster and is a standalone instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to create brand new queue managers instead of migrating your existing queue managers, you may find that you end up with slightly different attributes at the end of the day.

There are a number of cases where IBM MQ has a different default for a new attribute's default value depending one whether you have created a brand new queue manager or whether you have migrated it up to the new level.

I can think of one in IBM MQ V8, the CONNAUTH attribute. I believe it is left blank if you migrate up (thus turning off user ID and password checking) and is set to point to the 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS' object if you create a brand new queue manager (turning on user ID and password checking and mandating a password must be supplied by any remote connections).

Such things would not be caught by `dmpmqcfg` because it's a new attribute over and above what the V7.5 objects you dumped out would have.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making more work for yourself than necessary.  Plus there have been cases of dmpmqcfg not capturing all of the setmqaut and chlauth rules.  Also, what about messages in queue(s) that have not been consumed?

What is wrong with doing:

1. Uninstall V7.5
2. Install V9.0
3. Start all queue managers
4. Stop all queue managers
5. Uninstall V9.0
6. Install V9.1 and install FixPack 9.1.0.2

If this is on Linux, then it is really easy to do.

No need to backup message data, no need to backup configuration and finally, no need to worry about missing setmqaut and/or chlauth rules.